# How to use animations in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm new to this and i'm making a game with SpriteBuilder and cocos2D (latest relase) but i cant manage to get animations working.

I have this code:

```
id scaleHorDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration 5/30.f scaleX:0.75f scaleY:1.0f];

id scaleHorBouncing = [CCEaseBounceIn actionWithAction:scaleHorDown];
id scaleVerDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration 5/30.f scaleX:1.0f scaleY:0.65f];
id scaleVerBouncing = [CCEaseBounceInOut actionWithAction:scaleVerDown];

id shrink = [CCSequence actions:scaleHorBouncing,scaleVerBouncing, nil];

id swell = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration: duration * 15/30.f scale:1.10f];
id swellEase = [CCEaseElasticOut actionWithAction:swell];

id resetScale = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration * 5/30.f scale:1.0f];
id resetScaleBouncing = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:resetScale];

id buttonAction = [CCSequence actions: shrink, swellEase, resetScaleBouncing, nil];

[self runAction:buttonAction];
```

But it doesnt recognize most of the methods. I guess its a problem with the imports but i've tried a lot of things and nothing...

Thanks!

Comment: sprite builder comes with cocos2d 3.2 ... you are using a '2.x' syntax which has been deprecated. Just look at the cocos2d API reference here : http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/index.html

Comment: yup, actions now have the "CCAction" prefix but other than that they should be the same as before